# View not scrolling when simulator set to landscape mode iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I went through many blogs, stack flow questions and googled alot, but didn't get any solution to get my ScrollView work. I don't know why but my ScrollView works in portrait mode but not in landscape.

I am developing using xcode 5 for ios 7 devices. I developed my screen using storyboard. I added a ViewController on storyboard, removed the default UIView it contains, and added a ScrollView. In that ScrollView I added my subviews. Then I referenced the ScrollView to the scrollview object in the outlets.

This is my LoginViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end
```

This is my LoginViewController.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
@interface LoginViewController ()
@end
@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize scrollView;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

My scrollview scrolls when in portrait mode but not in landscape. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All your answers can be found in this video. It has done wonders for me. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgeNPRBrB18&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome Thanks for the video link. Its perfect.

Comment: do you have auto layout on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reset scroll view content size on screen orientation:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Scroll view frame most probably will change so you need to re-set content size.

if you have auto layout on set content size inside layoutSubviews:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

**Note**

Content size supposed to be larger than scroll view size. to scroll right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help hasan but i have already tried that but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add scrolling in scroll view check `scrollView` height.

If `scrollView.height > scrollview.content.height` scrollview did not scroll. But `scrollView.height < scrollview.content.height` scrollview will scroll....

So, the scrollview's content height is greater than the scrollview height is necessary for scrolling..

Therefore, you should do something like this:

`scrollView.contentSize.height=scrollView.height+50`